# how to do database handling in asp using vbscript

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to fetch data from (.mdb) file in my asp page, using vbscript, but when I run the page it always says that an error occurred in the server while processing the URL. I am using windows 7. Can anyone please tell me how to fix this?

the code I used is:

```
    `dim cn

    set cn=server.createobject("ADODB.Connection")
    cn.provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    cn.open "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\datalogin.mdb"

    dim ssql,rs
    ssql="select * from idpass where mid='fname' and pwd='lname'"
    set rs=server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
    set rs=cn.execute(ssql)`
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code I don't think you want both of these lines

```
set rs=server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
set rs=cn.execute(ssql)
```

You can either just use

```
set rs=cn.execute(ssql)
```

or use

```
set rs=server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.Open ssql,cn,0,1
```

However I can't see why this would cause an error as the second line should just override the first.  There are all sorts of things which could cause an error, there may be a mistake in your SQL, Your access database may be in a different location, or the IUSR account may not have the necessary permissions on the database.

You need to enable detailed error messages in order to pinpoint the problem, this is a good guide 
http://www.chestysoft.com/asp-error-messages.asp

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but could please tell me how to write this query properly. I don't know how to write the query in vbscript.

Comment: I can see nothing in the code you have provided that should cause an error.  Your query is written in valid SQL.  One possible cause of an error is if the table name and field names in your query don't match what's in the database.  There could also be a VBScript error somewhere in your page outside of the snippet of code you've provided.  Have you managed to enable detailed error messages as per the link I gave you.  It's something you really need to do to discover why your page doesn't work

Comment: John I have enabled it. But it seems that I am trying to run this in a Windows 7(64bit),, and that is the problem. I searched in the net, and I found problems occur in windows 7(64 bit). I have to try this in XP or Win7(32bit) system. But anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere.  The driver for JET (or Access) databases is 32 bit only, there isn't a 64 bit version.  If you open IIS manager, find the Application Pool which your site uses, right click on it and select "set application pool defaults" then one of the options you'll find is "Enable 32-bit Applications".  Set it to true.